# Що таке "срібная креш" у пісні "Як засядем, браття, коло чари"?

Tags: значення-слів, діалекти

У народній пісні "Як засядем, браття, коло чари" такий приспів:

> Кришталева чара – срібнеє дно,
>   Пити чи не пити – все одно.
>   Кришталева чара – **срібная креш**,
>   Пити чи не пити – все ж помреш.

Що це за "креш"? Схоже це якось пов'язано із самою "чарою".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Слово "креш", відоме з популярної пісні на вірші Юрія Федьковича, в академічних словниках української літературної мови не зафіксоване. Проте у художніх текстах це слово зустрічається у значеннях:

1. *вінця, обідок*
2. *чарка*.

Перше із цих значень може бути пов'язаним із польським *kres* ('лінія, край'). Тоді як друге, імовірно, утворилося за суміжністю значень (поетична метонімія).

> *Цей обрій — наче чорний **креш** // гіркої-гіркоти* — Василь Стус

Також може вживатися у значеннях *кришталь*.

Джерела:

- [ua-etymology.LiveJournal](http://ua-etymology.livejournal.com/330686.html)
- [Словник.ua](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/index.php?showtopic=4140)

Comment: Мені ця цитата більше сподобалася: "Отрути випив я, налитої по креш (Дм.Павличко)". І таке означення: "КРЕШ - серебряний поясочок у кришталевої чари. Монтується з метою запобігти сколюванню країв". Обидва з Словник.уа