# Що таке "шпагатівка"?

Tags: етимологія, значення-слів

Я вже [питав](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/372/) про пісню "Як засядем, браття, коло чари". Але там є ще одне слово, яке мені інтуїтивно зрозуміле, але хотілося б більше подробиць.

Що таке "шпагатівка"?

> Як засіли наші коло чаші -
>   Петро, Павло, Хведір, Миколай, -
>   Як смикнули тії **шпагатівки**,
>   То вони забули і про рай!

Зрозуміло що це, напевно, якийсь алкогольний напій (на кшталт буряківки чи іншого самогону), але чи пов'язана ця назва із словом "шпагат" і якщо так, то чому?

> ШПАГА́Т, у, чол.
>   1. Зсукана, випрядена товста нитка, що вживається для упаковування, зв'язування, зшивання і т. ін.; шворка.  *(СУМ-11)*

Пошук в інтернеті дає купу прикладів використання цього слова (саме у сенсі "алкогольний напій", але означення я не знайшов.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Як я зрозумів із [цієї](http://homedistiller.org/flavor/ukraine) англомовної статті, шпагатівка (там 'Shpahativka') – саркастична назва до міцного самогону, але не дуже [якісного](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:rlwdZSnCJp0J:lvivforever.org.ua/index.php/horilchanyi-tur/457-horilchanyi-leksykon%20&cd=5&hl=en&ct=clnk&lr=lang_en%7Clang_uk). Письменник [Братан Микола](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), у своєму романі «[Голодна кров](http://www.libros.am/book/read/id/225271/slug/golodna-krov)» описує ймовірне походження терміну через характерну дію на організм після вживання:

> ...мед при цьому належить настоювати на **шпагатівці**, яку він же
>   самовіль і жене, уміє це робити зі смаком, ось тільки так і не
>   втямить, чому цей лік **шпагатівкою** звуть. Хіба що **скручує** тебе, як
>   **шпагат**…

Ось пояснення з конспекту лекцій "[Українська мова](http://www.nua.kharkov.ua/eng/images/stories/Kafedri/Kaf_Ukrainovedenya/metod_obespechenie/Berest_Konspekt_lekciy_UM_RP-1.pdf)" для філологів, тема "Народна етимологія", сторінка 114:

> Як правило, ці етимології розраховані на створення комічних ситуацій:
>   *“А може, у Світлогорську скликається міжнародний конгрес спирторобів
>   для дегустації Вустиних самогонок, які вона вміла варити з усіх
>   відомих злаків, ягід, з садовини й городини, з табуреток, з макухи,
>   силосу, сінажу і навіть з того **шпагату**, яким на цукрозаводах
>   зав’язують мішки з цукром: саме звідси й пішли початки славетної
>   української пісні про те, “як смикнули тої **шпагатівки**...”* (П.
>   Загребельний).

Крім того, є схожа назва "**мотузяна**", але вона зустрічається лише ось в [цьому PDF-документі](http://is.muni.cz/th/264713/ff_b/Bak_prace_Igor.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

На виході змійовика чіплявся *шпагат*, щоб горілка стікала рівніше. (Ймовірно, саме тому самогон можуть називати *шпагатівкою*.)

---

Подібної думки [«Етимологічний словник української мови»](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8)  (том 6, сторінка 455):

> [**шпага́тівка**] «самогон» Мо; — польське *розм.* **[szpagatówka](https://sjp.pwn.pl/doroszewski/szpagatowka;5504501.html)**, **szpagat** «(*жарт.*) **горілка**»; — утворення, повʼязане зі шпага́т; назва мотивується тим, що при саморобній дистиляції самогону рідина стікає тонкою цівкою з труби в посуд по привʼязаному до кінця трубки шпагату. — Див. ще **шпага́т**.

Comment: Іван, цікава інформація. Чи можете навести якісь підтвердження?

Comment: Так мені мій дід розповідав ще в дитинстві. Інших підтвержень не маю.

Comment: Тобто це самогон? Щодо походження назви - без підтвердження з боку дослідників це скоріше приклад народної етимології, як про це вже написав Jack.

Comment: @Artemix, як на мене, це достатньо реалістична версія походження назв _шпагатівка_ і _мотузяна_ (на відміну від жартівливої версії у відповіді пана Jack про те, що із самих мотузок хтось самогон варив) — хоча так, звісно, без жодних доведень поки що.

Comment: Не останню роль відіграє те, що стакання мотузкою було, як я розумію, остіннім етапом виготовлення. А останній відбивається найбільше. Згадаємо назву тижня у росіян «неделя» (спочатку так називали лише останній день тижня) або використання слова «лѣто» у значенні «рік» (нагадаю, що «літо» вважалося раніше останньою порою року, рік починався у вересні).

Comment: @Sasha Оце вже посилання. Хоча навіть словник вказує що "мотивується" а не "походить".

Answer (score 2):

Додаток до затвердженого [допису](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/453/585) від пана Джек.

---

Словник українських синонїмів • [Олекса Вусик](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) • [Анатолїй Поповський](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)

> **Горілка** […] шпагатівка

---

[Русалїї](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=F4TXAAAAMAAJ&q=%D1%88%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) • [Василь Скуратївський](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%84%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)

> Настойки робили на 20-градусній горілці. Якщо порушувалась пропорція, то такий виріб у народі йменували саркастичними назвами: *спотикач, шпагатівка, мокруха, чикилдиха* тощо.

---

Також є згадка в книзї [„Таємницї львівської горілки“](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=rwgTAQAAIAAJ&q=%D1%88%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) від [Юрія Винничука](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D1%83%D0%BA_%D0%AE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), але там фраґмент не повний, тому контексту не зрозуміти.

---

На однїй москвомовнїй [зустрічцї](https://kino.sxnarod.com/topic331344.html) позначають як технїчний спирт. Перекладенї мною фраґменти:

> > > > Але ж бо спирт був зерновий, а не технїчний.
> > >
> > > І технїчний був. Така горілка була позначена: печатка зі шнуром. В Українї називали — „шпагатївка“.
> >
> > І справдї, памʼятаю таке. Використовував для компресїв, і для инших цїлей.
>
> Не дуже коректне означення. Етиловий спирт з зерна чи з иншої сировини (якої саме — не знаю, я не технолоґ спиртпрома) звуть офіцїйно „харчовий“, що має ту саму формулу — С<sub>2</sub>H<sub>5</sub>OH. Але як на мене, пити таке, навіть якщо розбавляти водою — дикість і труїння свого орґанїзму. „Шпагатївка“ дїйсно не робилась зерном. […]

Comment: Версію про печатку із шнурком ("шпагатом") здається теж зустрічав.

Comment: @Artemix, теж цікава версія (на додачу про [мотузок, який чіпляли до змійовика](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/2704)). Можливо, вони обидві правдиві в тому сенсі, що в часи поширення печатки зі шнурком вже вживане слово шпагатівка «перекочувало» на рідину під такою печаткою. Те, що печатка з мотузком є первісною причиною назви, могло б спростувати використання слова до виготовлення рідини під такою печаткою, але дати мені наразі невідомі (пісня зафіксована у 1955 в «Українські народні пісні. Книга 2» (Київ, «Мистецтво», 1955) на сторінці 187 — але це мало про що каже).

Answer (score 2):

Підсумую.

Слова *шпагатівка* і *мотузяна* точно означають певну категорію алкогольних напоїв (можливо, самогон чи ширшу категорію).

Версії походження слова:

1. Від мотузка, який чіпляли до змійовика.
2. Від мотузка, що був частиною печатки на пляшках.
3. (Жартівлива) Від того, що його могли варити навіть із самих мотузок.

Comment: -1: весь текст цієї відповіді дублює версії, запропоновані в інших відповідях.

Comment: @bytebuster, так. [І це нормально](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/70619) — робити відповідь, що підсумовує інші відповіді.

Comment: не варто штучно притягати ситуацію, яка виникає навколо запитання, яке має 296 answers, і запитання, яке має 3 відповіді. Окрім того, якщо таке залишати, то варто вказувати авторів версій і оновлювати дайджест, коли зʼявлятимуться нові відповіді.

Comment: @bytebuster, «варто вказувати авторів версій» — так, пункти мали бути посиланнями, просто в той момент не вистачило часу, мусив бігти (але і в такому вигляді відповідь має сенс, хоч і є гіршою, ніж запросто могла би бути); щодо оновлювати — зовсім необов'язково, відповідь може підсумовувати відоме на момент її створення, а далі як складеться. Не плутайте, будь ласка, «те, що було б краще» і «те, що є обов'язковим». Хоча я цілком згоден із Вами в тому, що так, як кажете, справді було б краще.